# How to manage a long (days long) python process

Tags: python, django, background-process

I have a large (over 600,000 records) database as part of a Django app. The app stores information collected from various open data web services. Every so often (maybe once a week or less) I need to check these web services to see if any of the data has been updated.

I've written a python script to do this. It works, but it is very slow and I often get this error well before it can complete: ConnectionError: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer

Based on some experiments, I think this process will take several days to complete. Besides optimizing my script, what is the best way to handle this type of long running python process?

Comment: Have you considered having your database itself know when the data has been updated, e.g., a `timestamp` column?  This would entirely alleviate the need to check for updates via slow comparisons after doing full table pulls, rather than just querying 'which rows have been updated since mm/dd/yyyy'

Comment: That's a great idea, and I do have a timestamp column. However, it doesn't help me the _first_ time I need to check the dataset.

Comment: Try using a separate script to access the database? If you leave the one that is working day long alone, you could avoid the issue.

Comment: I will try breaking the script down to one web service each. Also going to look into Django 1.5's new "object.save(update_fields=['name'])" to further reduce overhead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at [celery](http://celeryproject.org/) it should easily enable you to assign background jobs to multiple workers (which can also run on different machines). Also it enables you to queue jobs again if the fail and retry later on...

To optimize you your scripts you should probably look into using multiprocessing or using asynchronous libraries like [gevent](http://www.gevent.org/) (escpecially if you have jobs that do a lot of I/O like calling web services) which enable you to process a lot of simultanous connections (up to 100s/1000s) in parallel.

Comment: I will look into both of those. I have read some about them, but didn't know if I needed something so heavy for this. Probably do.

Comment: Especially celery will enable you to split one process into many small jobs, which can be processed seperately, retried independently and do not disturb each other when failing. Don't see it as a heavy solution, you mainly need the python celery packages and a queue for the jobs (maybe you are already using redis, then you can use it--if you do not want to install a stand alone message queue you can also use your database, especially for development/testing)

Comment: I'm also looking into this package, which looks a bit simpler than celery and might be all that I need: http://huey.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

Comment: Don't know huey, but it seems to point in the right direction... What I liked about celery are its powerful 'retry' possibilities, which turned out to be very useful when dealing with external web services (which time out usually..)... http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/master/userguide/tasks.html#retrying